# Complexity of a special matrix

Tags: ds.algorithms, algebraic-complexity

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ $\in \mathbb C$ with $|x| = |y| = |z| = 1$.

Has the following matrix (call it $S$) been studied before?

\begin{bmatrix}
1 &x &xy &xyz \newline
\bar{x} &1 &y &yz \newline
\bar{x}\bar{y} &\bar{y} &1 &z \newline
\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} &\bar{y}\bar{z} &\bar{z} &1 \newline
\end{bmatrix}

Let $S_{\mathbb C}$ be imaginary part of $S$ and $S_{\mathbb R}$ be real part of $S$.
Note that $Rank(S) = Rank(S_{\mathbb R}) = 1$ since both are products of a column matrix and a row matrix.

Let $V$ be a column vector of size $n$.
For a generalization of the above matrix to size $n$:

$(1)$ What is the complexity of matrix-vector multiplications $S_{\mathbb C}V$?

$(2)$ What is the complexity of finding $S_{\mathbb C}^{-1}$?

$(3)$ What is the complexity of finding $S_{\mathbb C}^{-1}V$?

Corresponding complexity of $(1)$ for $SV$ and $S_{\mathbb R}V$ is linear.

My guess is $(1)$ and $(3)$ should also be linear.

Comment: I'm curious about motivation behind this problem.